# PHP evaluate class sub member

Tags: php

```
class Customer{
    public $country;
    public function __construct(){
      $this->country = new Country();
      $this->country->name = "USA";
   }

}

class Country{

}
```

I want to print the country name, but i have the following context only.

```
 $c = new Customer();
 $member = "country.name";// i cant decide on this, this is what i get as a parameter
```

Can you please suggest how I can print the country name with the provided country.name string?

The solution im building here is for email template

`"the country that good for you is {country.name}"`

So I will replace country.name to USA with the help of `$c` and `$member`

Comment: Pass `$members` to `__construct`? `$c->country->name = $members;`?

Comment: If your class has public members then there isn't really much you can do at runtime to enforce any invariants it might have other than check all its members (```if null !== $this->country && !empty $this->country->name```) etc.  You can force things to be set via constructors of course, but then there's still nothing to stop a sloppy or mischievous programmer overwriting that value after construction.  If these are just simple DTOs then that's fine but it might be worth considering non-public properties with getters instead.

Comment: Are you using Twig? It seems like you are using Twig.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by iterating over the elements in your `$members` string, and stepping further into the object each time:

```
// First initialise our reference to the "top-level" object
$ref = $c;
// Break apart our steps
$steps = explode('.', $members);

// For every element in the array, dig deeper into the object hierarchy
while ($step = array_shift($steps)) {
    $ref = $ref->{$step};
}

// Once the loop is finished, $ref will be set to $c->country->name
echo $ref;
```

See https://eval.in/954722

Comment: I dont know why, but your code works on the link you gave, at my and I am getting the error: `Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Country::$name has no effect` I dont know if that matter, I'm using Laravel Model....

Comment: @Shazam Updated the answer to remove the reference assignments - I think it should work fine with Laravel models now, although I don't have a copy to test at the moment.